# Creating a 2nd virtual disk with PERC H700

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, dell-perc

I currently have just 1 virtual disk set up with raid 0 for my OS, and would like to create a 2nd virtual disk for just storage.

Will I have any data loss/issues with the existing virtual disk by creating a 2nd VD and adding just the new unassigned physical drive to it?

Might be a stupid question but I'd rather be sure than accidentally wipe my servers OS drive.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details about your current raid configuration. If you used all disks for RAID-0, then you'd better backup everything important and start from scratch. But, be aware that you won't be able to create 2 RAID types with 2 disks only.

Cheers!

Comment: Current raid configuration is just 1 disk with raid 0, I just want to add a 2nd raid 0 drive separate from the current OS drive.

Comment: If you have only 1 disk inserted in your server, then it's not a RAID. Even RAID0 requires 2 disks minimum. If you didn't do any configuration with it - then you don't use any raid options atm

Comment: You clearly have never used a perc h700. There's no passthrough, you have to create a virtual disk and create a raid in order to use the physical drive. I don't want raid. I just want an OS drive, and a storage drive.

Comment: I might forgot if these controllers got JBOD, in case if they doesn't - then you should be fine, your newly inserted drive won't interfere with the one already installed. Just create another RAID0, and you're good to go.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I could just do that. I just wanted to be sure that creating a 2nd virtual disk doesn't rebuild the first virtual disk.